# ERROR /usr/libexec/mysqld: Incorrect information in file

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am seeing this error after a reboot and some other slowdown issues. MYSQL keeps restarting, and I assume that means InnoDB is recovering, though I am not familiar enough with the process to know for sure. I am running CentOS 6 and saw this:

```
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
InnoDB: In a MySQL replication slave the last master binlog file
InnoDB: position 0 256214410, file name mysqld-bin.000003
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 390069474, file name /var/lib/mysql/.000105
190105 17:11:09  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 91 3960852448
InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of uncommitted transactions
190105 17:11:09  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 0 3103647860, 655 rows to undo
190105 17:11:09 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Incorrect information in file: './empire/member_list.frm'
190105 17:11:09 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Incorrect information in file: './empire/member_list.frm'
190105 17:11:09 [Note] Recovering after a crash using /var/lib/mysql/
190105 17:11:09 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
190105 17:11:09 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
190105 17:11:09 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
190105 17:11:09 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
190105 17:11:09 [ERROR] Aborting

190105 17:11:09  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
190105 17:11:09 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Incorrect information in file:
```

Here is what the my.cnf file looks like:

```
 The MySQL server
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table = 1
log-bin=/var/lib/mysql/
#binlog-do-db=leadtraffic
#binlog-do-db=fullemedia
binlog-ignore-db=supp
server-id=5
#master-host=XXX
#master-user=XXX
#master-password=XXX
#master-connect-retry=60
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-locking
skip-name-resolve
relay-log=/data1/mysqld/mysqld-relay-bin
skip-slave
#set-variable    = join_buffer_size=60M
set-variable    = key_buffer=128M
set-variable    = max_allowed_packet=30M
set-variable    = table_cache=64
set-variable    = sort_buffer=8M
set-variable    = record_buffer=2M
set-variable    = myisam_sort_buffer_size=8M
set-variable    = thread_cache=4
set-variable    = thread_concurrency=2
set-variable    = max_connections=500
set-variable    = wait_timeout=3600

#
#replicate-ignore-table=dreamdirect.member_list_old
#replicate-ignore-table=dreamdirect.realtime_info
#replicate-ignore-table=dreamdirect.realtime_info1
#replicate-ignore-table=dreamdirect.realtime_info2
#replicate-ignore-table=dreamdirect.camp_realtime_info
#replicate-ignore-table=fullemedia.realtime_info
#replicate-ignore-table=fullemedia.realtime_info1
#replicate-ignore-table=fullemedia.realtime_info2
#replicate-ignore-table=test.*
#replicate-ignore-table=test.md5supp

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#set-variable   = bdb_cache_size=64M

# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
tmpdir          = /var/tmp/
#log-update     = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

innodb_data_home_dir=
innodb_data_file_path = /data1/ibdata/ibdata1:5000M;/data1/ibdata/ibdata2:5000M;/data1/ibdata/ibdata3:5000M;/data1/ibdata/ibdata4:5000M:autoextend
set-variable = innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G
set-variable = innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=5M
innodb_log_group_home_dir= /data1/iblogs
innodb_log_arch_dir = /data1/iblogs
set-variable = innodb_log_files_in_group=3
##
set-variable = innodb_log_file_size=100M
set-variable = innodb_log_buffer_size=16M
set-variable = innodb_file_io_threads=8
set-variable = innodb_lock_wait_timeout=100
set-variable = innodb_autoextend_increment=200
#
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_log_archive=0

set-variable = innodb_lock_wait_timeout=100
#innodb_flush_method = O_DSYNC

[mysqldump]
quick
set-variable    = max_allowed_packet=16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
#safe-updates   # Remove the comment character if you are not familiar with SQL

[isamchk]
set-variable    = key_buffer=2M
set-variable    = sort_buffer=1M
set-variable    = read_buffer=1M
set-variable    = write_buffer=1M

[myisamchk]
set-variable    = key_buffer=20M
set-variable    = sort_buffer=20M
set-variable    = read_buffer=2M
set-variable    = write_buffer=2M
```

Is it possible this is a buffer issue, that it keeps going to the old data from the data file? That's a newbie guess.

Comment: Th error log explains why it can't start and suggests a very specific potential cause. Did you check if anything was listening on port 3306? Try `netstat -nap | grep ::3306`

Comment: Nothing happened when I ran that. Just came back to command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most relevant clue:

```
190105 17:11:09 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
190105 17:11:09 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
190105 17:11:09 [ERROR] Aborting
```

It's telling you that another daemon process is already using port 3306. Only one process can listen on a given port at a time, so when you try to start mysqld, it can't bind to that port, and it shuts down.

It's most likely another instance of mysqld that's already running. You can use `ps -elw | grep mysqld` to confirm this.

Before you can start mysql server the way you are trying to do, you need to make sure any other instances are shut down. If all else fails, you may have to use `kill -9` to do it, and make sure to shut down the launcher `mysqld_safe` too (if there is one running), or else it'll just restart the mysqld process.

---

The other error you saw about "incorrect information in file" is indicating that one of your table definitions is corrupt -- the one for `empire.member_list`. That's not enough to stop mysqld from starting, but you won't be able to use that table.

If your table uses MyISAM, ARCHIVE, or CSV engines, you can try [REPAIR TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/repair-table.html) (please read the documentation, I'm not here to type in docs that already exist).

If your table was InnoDB, or repair doesn't work for some reason, then restore your table from your most recent backup.

If you have no backup, then treat this as a learning experience. You should get into the habit of making backups.

Comment: Thanks, Bill. I think the TCP/IP error came from the system trying to start MYSQL while I tried to do it from command line. 

The server is running now, but it is missing a lot of table data, probably related to the empire.member.list issue. Can that be restored?

There is only mysqld and mysqld running right now.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Replacing the file with backup didn't work and now it's finding other corrupt files as well.

Comment: "Replacing the file with backup" sounds like you're just moving FRM files around manually. That's not restoring a backup. Most attempts to fiddle with the internal files of MySQL result in greater corruption.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I understand. I took this over after my admin retired and disappeared and now am trying to piece things back together. The database runs at about 85% complete, but key elements are missing. Could I restore the InnoDB databases?

Comment: You should hire a new admin who knows how to operate MySQL. Or else spend the time to learn how to do it yourself. Using Stack Overflow as a substitute for having someone on staff with basic operational skills is not a good business plan.

Comment: There are dozens of good books on operating MySQL. Try [Effective MySQL Backup and Recovery](https://www.amazon.com/Effective-MySQL-Backup-Recovery-Oracle/dp/0071788573/) or [High Performance MySQL](https://www.amazon.com/High-Performance-MySQL-Optimization-Replication/dp/1449314287/)

Comment: I know. This happened rather quickly and I have taught myself a tremendous amount. I initially thought this was a simple problem. This is a side venture that doesn't have much in the way of finances to support a full-time admin, but I may do that anyway. Problem is, I wouldn't even know where to look for one.

Comment: The best database backup and recovery specialists for MySQL are: https://twindb.com. They have free tools and information, or paid services.

Comment: To find a part-time or full-time database admin, you may be able to hire a freelancer for short-term work at https://www.upwork.com. The best MySQL DBA services are at https://www.percona.com/services/managed-services/percona-dba-service but they require an annual contract and that gets kind of spendy. Another MySQL service provider is https://pythian.com/dba-services, they might do short-term work.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much for the help.